# Creating a format string for NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I have a date in the format `Tue, 29 May 2012 00:56:14 +0000` from an XML file, which is not under my control so the original format cannot be changed.

I was researching for how to create format strings for `NSDateFormatter`, found [this page](http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/), and came up with the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'YYYY' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'Z"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *parsedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

However, after parsing the date above, `Tue, 29 May 2012 00:56:14 +0000`, with this format string I get `2011-12-27 00:56:14 +0000`. So the time is correct, but the date is all jumbled.

Could someone with some more knowledge of `NSDateFormatter` please explain why this isn't working? To my knowledge the format string seems correct, but apparently it is not. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you make sure the you use the correct format patterns?

Comment: My format pattern is in the code above. It seems to me, based on my research, that it is correct, but `NSDateFormatter` is not correctly parsing the text with the format pattern I gave it, so I suspect that I do not understand how to correctly use format patterns. That's why I'm wondering if someone can help show me where I went wrong in creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your year format string should be lower case, 'yyyy'

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believe I missed that.